# Change base domain name for Lets Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have used Let's Encrypt to allow me to set up SSL/HTTPS on my server.

The issue is that I run a number of sub-domains too, which I included on the initial install, but looking back now - the certificate details show that it was issued to one of my sub-domains.

I'm wanting to change this to my base domain, but I'm just not sure how to do this.

I have tried running `letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.me -d www.example.me  -d mysql.example.me`

This went through the process but did not change anything, as the certs are already issued.

How can I change the certificates now, or reissue them so that they are issued to my base domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply force renewal:

```
./certbot --apache -d example.me -d www.example.me -d mysql.example.me --force-renewal
```

Reference: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/change-base-domain-name-for-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-in-certbot/16955/2

Comment: Since certbot came out I had managed to solve this. Doing the above was pretty much how i did it.

Comment: No good for me. This does not change the base / common name of the certificate for me.  It did not pick either the first name I listed nor the last name. Instead, it left it as it was (which was one of the others in the list).

Answer (score 2):

You can revoke your current cert and reissue with -d example.com in first followed by subdomains.

To revoke do:

```
$ letsencrypt revoke --cert-path example-cert.pem
```

And reissue with the command you already have.

*NOTE:* be aware of usage limits or you may end up not issuing more certificates for sometime.

Comment: Maybe if you wait until your certs expire and reissue with -d example.com as you stated it will work too.

Comment: Apparently it works if you simply use --force-renewal instead of revoking
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/change-base-domain-name-for-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-in-certbot/16955/2

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's be clear about your question:

> the certificate details show that it was issued to one of my sub-domains.

You can get single cert for multiple domains (multiple -d arguments) and only one gets listed as CN (COMMON NAME) and others are just SAN (Subject Alt Name). Current LE's limit is 100 domain names in one cert. I'm not sure about official LE client, but in my case using [simp_le](https://github.com/kuba/simp_le) the last one domain specified is used as CN and the others as SANs. It looks like you want to have your main domain become CN? Then just try it as last -d argument.

Now if you run LE client for specific domain(s) and the same certificate already exists on your system, then LE checks cert's validity period and does nothing if it is (by default) more than 30 days to expiration. This is why you can put LE command to cron job and let it run every day and certificates will be renewed only when needed.

> How can I change the certificates now, or reissue them so that they are issued to my base domain?

Just simply remove old certs from your system and try to execute LE command again. Be aware of -d order to get desired domain as CN and not SAN.

Be carefull and don't hit [LE CA's rate limits](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/rate-limits-for-lets-encrypt/6769) (20 certs per domain per week)...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `--expand` directive to add additional subdomains as SANs to an existing certificate (which probably just revokes and reissues the certificate behind the scenes).

Just be sure to include all of your existing domains.

So if you originally requested:

```
-d example.com -d www.example.com
```

... you can expand this with a new subdomain `click.example.com` by issuing a new command:

```
--expand -d example.com -d www.example.com -d click.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using the latest certbot version:

```
sudo certbot certonly --cert-name foo.com --standalone -d foo.com -d bar.net --force-renewal
```

I had a certificate issued to `foo.com`, `bar.com` and `baz.com` and wanted to remove `baz.com`.